# How can fixed top header when scroll down mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The script is working, when scrolling down it does place the top header at the top of the window but unfortunately there're a couple of small issue that are driving me bananas!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var $window = jQuery(window);
   $window.scroll(function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= 130) {
    jQuery('.custom-site-header').addClass('top-header');
    
   } else {
      jQuery('.custom-site-header').removeClass('top-header');
   }
   });
   });
```

```css
.top-header
   {
   position: fixed;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1000;
   background: #fff;
      height:80px;
      top:0px;
      
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="custom-site-header">Fixed Header</div>
    </div>
   <section class="body_section">
   </section>
   </div>
```

Comment: you need to provide us with a code snippet or tell us what u have tried , and what issues u are seeing.

Comment: What "couple of small issue" are the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. Hope this will help !!!!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   var $window = jQuery(window);
   $window.scroll(function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= 130) {
    jQuery('.custom-site-header').addClass('top-header');
    
   } else {
      jQuery('.custom-site-header').removeClass('top-header');
   }
   });
   });
```

```css
.top-header
   {
   position: fixed;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1000;
   background: #fff;
      height:80px;
      top:0px;
      
   }
   .body_section
   {
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="custom-site-header">Fixed Header</div>
    </div>
   <section class="body_section">
   </section>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanx for your help. its working fine.